# Background Tasks not working for WatchOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm experiencing a very peculiar issue. I'm trying to build a simple WatchOS & iOS app that just detects when an iPhone is disconnected from the watch and the watch sends a local notification via the companion app telling the user it has been disconnected. I've accomplished this by setting a background task on the watch App that checks at intervals if the iPhone is reachable. Everything works on the simulator (when connected to the debugger), however I realize that the background tasks do not execute whenever I run on a physical device, or whenever I'm disconnected from the debugger via the simulator. I've googled and found similar issues from others, but no clear answer or even suggestions to fix it.

Here's a snippet of view model code from watchOS

```
class WatchViewModel: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate, ObservableObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

var session: WCSession
@Published var messageText = ""
init(session: WCSession = .default){
    self.session = session
    super.init()
    self.session.delegate = self
    session.activate()
    
}
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    
    
}

func ConnectionWatch(){
    
    let dateset = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5) // 10 seconds (0.10 * 60.0)
    
    WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: dateset, userInfo: nil){
        (error) in
        if (error == nil){
            print("Background Refresh Started")
            if self.session.isReachable {
                print("Session is Active. iPhone Reachability (\(self.session.isReachable))")
                self.triggerAlert()
            } else {
                
                print("Session is Inactive. iPhone Reachability (\(self.session.isReachable))")
                self.session.activate()
                self.triggerAlert()
                
            }
        }
    }
}


func triggerAlert(){
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "iPhone disconnected"
    content.body = "Your iPhone is off or out of range."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    // Show notification by number of seconds from now
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)
    
    // Choose a random identifier
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    // Add our notification request
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

This is the code from the ExtensionDelegate

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, ObservableObject {

private let watchmodel = WatchViewModel()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
   
    watchmodel.ConnectionWatch()
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
   
}

func applicationWillResignActive() {
   
}

func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        
        if WKExtension.shared().applicationState == .background {
            
            switch task {
            case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:


                print("Background Task triggered")

                watchmodel.ConnectionWatch()
                backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)



            default:
                
                task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long did you wait for the task to execute? When not running under Xcode I would expect it to be at least 15 minutes, possibly longer, before your task would be scheduled.  What if `error` isn't `nil`? - You don't do anything with the error.

Comment: I can’t see the point since  Watch already displays an icon on top of the watch face when the paired iPhone is not in range anymore. 
Anyway maybe the problem relies in the timing being too frequent for the background task on the watch application, 5 seconds is really low and could be just postponed by the system to preserve the battery.

Comment: @valeCocoa The reason I'm trying this out is because I've actually left my iPhone at a location before and didn't realize until I got home. So the watch showed the icon that it was disconnected yes, but I didn't get a prompt or anything while in transit.  I see your point with timing intervals though. I set it at 5 seconds really to test if the tasks would execute, in production I would set it for much later. It works in the simulator, but when disconnected from the debugger it doesn't. Is there a standard time that background tasks are executed?

Comment: @Paulw11 fair point. I didn't do any error handling. I'll try this and let you know. However, given the nature of the app, 15 min would be quite a while for the background task to execute. By that timeI could be miles away from the iPhone. Is this a standard time or can I set a reasonable time?

Comment: @KevonBrown simple answer: there isn’t. Complex answer… well refer to the background task scheduling documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/background_execution/using_background_tasks at *budgeting you’re apps background time* section.

Comment: @KevonBrown BTW in Find My on your iPhone you can enable to be notified on your paired  Watch when the phone is left behind for this purpose, so I still don't see the point…

Comment: @valeCocoa thanks for the link. That Find my feature is enabled and it doesn't work. At least it didn't when my phone was left behind. The battery was on and connected to the internet. But in any case its not a serious project, I'm new to WatchOS development so I just thought it would be cool to see if I could actually create an app that could do that. So if anything, this is really just for learning

Comment: Find my works for me.  One point is that it won't tell you if you leave your phone at home; it assumes you are happy to leave things behind at your own home. If you go somewhere else with your phone and watch and then leave with just your watch you should get a notification that you have left your phone behind.

Comment: @KevonBrown Well in terms of learning WatchOS development I think starting right away with a topic such as background tasks is taking the hardest path. To each his own, some prefer to start with smaller projects, other needs to go for testing the limits as soon as possible. Anyway if you keep up with this project, perhaps you’d also wanna take into account the possibility that the user has more than one Watch paired.